# Transposing from rows into columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, transpose

I have a table like this:

```
Name    State       Amount
------------------------------
Pump 1  Present     339
Pump 1  Optimized   88
```

I want to transpose it to something like this:

```
Pump 1  Present     339 Optimized   88
```

How can I do this with MS SQL 2000? I tried to search for a solution, but couldn't find the most fitting one.

Comment: Can you make your example a bit bigger to make it clearer what output you want? For example, are "Present" and "Optimized" the only states possible, or can there be others? Will all of the states always be present for each pump, or can some pumps have more than others - and if so, what do you want the output to look like in this case?

Comment: For each pump it will have two entries one Present and one Optimized. What I want is to have these states in one row instead of two rows for each pump. I hope this make more clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @t table(Name    varchar(10), State       varchar(10), Amount int)
insert into @t
select 'Pump 1',  'Present',     339  union all
select 'Pump 1',  'Optimized',   88 

select name,
max(case when state='Present' then 'Present' end),
max(case when state='Present' then Amount end),
max(case when state='Optimized' then 'Optimized' end),
max(case when state='Optimized' then Amount end)
from @t
group by name
```